# Match the codes and copy columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL Server 2008. I have 2 tables `Table1` & `Table2`.

`Table1` has columns

```
SchoolCode, District, Type, SchoolName
```

and `Table2` has columns

```
SchoolCode1, District1, Type1, SchoolName1
```

`SchoolCode` columns in both tables have the same codes like "1234"; code is the same in both `schoolcode` columns.

Now I want to copy the `District`, `Type` and `SchoolName` column values from `Table1` to `Table2` if `SchoolCode` in both tables is same.

I think the query will use join but I don't know how it works. Any help on how I can do this task?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far - we'll be glad help - but we won't just write the whole code for you .....

Comment: Hint: A way of doing this is with an `UPDATE` statement with an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use an update statement in join if by copying over you mean updating rows

```
update t2
set 
    District1= District, 
    Type1= Type, 
    SchoolName1= SchoolName
from Table1 t1
join
Table2 t2
on t1.SchoolCode=t2.SchoolCode1
```

Answer (score 1):

I could give you a little bit of idea. here is it:

```
Insert into table2 (District1, Type1, SchoolName1)
SELECT District, Type, SchoolName
FROM table1
where table1.Schoolcode=table2.Schoolcode1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Inner join to update data from table 1 to table 2, Inner join will join values that are equal. .  To learn more about joins, I highly recommend you to read the below article

[SQLServer Joins Explained - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Please refer the below code, for the convenience I have used the temporary tables..

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
(
    SchoolCode  INT, 
    District    VARCHAR(MAX), 
    Type        VARCHAR(MAX), 
    SchoolName  VARCHAR(MAX)
)

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE
(
    SchoolCode1  INT, 
    District1   VARCHAR(MAX), 
    Type1       VARCHAR(MAX), 
    SchoolName1 VARCHAR(MAX)
)




INSERT INTO @Table1
        ( SchoolCode ,District , Type , SchoolName
        )
VALUES  ( 1 ,'DIS1' ,'X' ,'A'),
        ( 2 ,'DIS2' ,'Y' ,'B'),
        ( 3 ,'DIS3' ,'Z' ,'C'),
        ( 4 ,'DIS4' ,'D' ,'D'),
        ( 5 ,'DIS5' ,'K' ,'E')



INSERT INTO @Table2
        ( SchoolCode1 ,District1 , Type1 , SchoolName1
        )
VALUES  ( 1 ,'DIS1' ,'X' ,'A'),
        ( 2 ,NULL ,'Z' ,NULL),
        ( 3 ,'DIS3' ,'Z' ,'C'),
        ( 4 ,NULL ,'Z' ,'S'),
        ( 5 ,'DIS5' ,'K' ,'E')
--BEFORE

SELECT * FROM @Table1
SELECT * FROM @Table2

--Logic UPDATE Table 2
UPDATE t2 SET   t2.District1 = t1.District,
                t2.Type1 = t1.Type,
                t2.SchoolName1 = t1.SchoolName
FROM @Table1 t1
INNER JOIN @Table2 t2 ON t1.SchoolCode = t2.SchoolCode1
-- End Logic UPDATE Table 2

--AFTER
SELECT * FROM @Table1
SELECT * FROM @Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join tables in an `UPDATE` statement.

Note, I have aliased the tables, `table1` and `table2` as `t1` and `t2` respectively.

This is what I did:

```
create table Table1
(SchoolCode varchar(50),
District  varchar(50),[Type]  varchar(50),SchoolName  varchar(50))
go
create table Table2
(SchoolCode1 varchar(50), District1  varchar(50),[Type1]  varchar(50),SchoolName1  varchar(50))
go
insert into table1 values ('1234','District1','High','Cool School')
insert into table1 values ('2222','District2','Lower','Leafy School')
insert into table2 (SchoolCode1) values ('1234')
go
update t2
set District1 = District,
    Type1 = [Type],
    SchoolName1 = SchoolName
from table1 t1 
join table2 t2
on t2.SchoolCode1 = t1.SchoolCode
go
select * from table2
go
```